# Hersey Cookies and Creame Treat

Tags: dessert, melting-chocolate

I am planning on making a cute little desert for my family that involves steam melting (putting the bars in a glass bowl under steam) hersheys Cookies and Cream chocolate bars and then pouring them in a ice tray as a mold. However I want to coat the White Chocolate in the Milk Chocolate upon pouring them into the mold. Any ideas of how i could do that due to it seeming quite impossible in my mind?

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you have to either pour the hot one over the cold one, or dip cold in hot.

Freeze the first solid section in the moulds, then set on a wire baking tray & pour over your second layer.  This method will bind to the wire if you're not careful.

Alternatively, dip the cold in the hot & lay on a non-stick surface. This method tends to spread out a bit, so leave plenty of room around each chunk. Alternatively, don't dip to full-depth to allow for some run-off.

DaringGourmet has a recipe showing both methods, though over a different substrate - [Marzipan Truffles](https://www.daringgourmet.com/chocolate-marzipan-truffles/)

Answer (score 3):

Option 3 (options 1 and 2 in answer by Tetaujun)

Melt milk chocolate and paint into the molds. Freeze 20 minutes, then pour the melted C&C bar. Back into freezer.

You will have one side uncoated, so serve wth that side down